# Understanding password_verify();

Tags: php

I have built a very simple login/registration script which uses the password hash function as follows:

```
$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

All that does it takes my password and pops its into my DB in the format I expected. I am having problems with the login part and using the `password_verify()` function, my login script i very simple for now and is prone to SQL injection but I am simply wanting to understand how this works.

Here is my login script:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

ob_start();

include('db_con.php');

$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password']; 

$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);

$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

session_start();
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
header("location:home.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

I do not know at which point I need to use `password_verify()`, as I know it takes 2 parameters, one being the password and another being the hash?

Comment: You have major SQL injection vulnerabilities in this code that will get your site hacked. Why are you coding this way? Practice safe code from day one. The docs include a clear example of usage of `password_verify`. http://php.net/password_verify

Comment: Did you read my question? I am aware its prone to SQL injection

Comment: Firstly, please use PDO and prepared statements. Secondly, you should search for the username, and then compare against the password, that way you know if the user exists and if the password is correct. Thirdly, you haven't hashed the password when you are comparing against the one in the database. Fourthly, you should use a randomly generated salt, rather than an identical one for all passwords, that defeats the purpose of hashing with salt.

Comment: Yes, I did read the question, and the question remains: Why are you writing dangerous code instead of starting off right with parameterized queries? You're either a) creating more work for yourself or b) going to forget to fix it later.

Comment: You need to use `password_verify`. You cannot just hash the password again and look if it's the same as in the db. It will generate a different hash, no matter what. That's why you need to use `password_verify`. In the hash you get and save there is the salt, algorithm and cost saved, everything to verify the password with `password_verify`

Comment: @Vilsol The password hashing api automatically generates a secure salt.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois yes, but he needs something to compare it against, otherwise it generates a random hash each time.

Comment: @Vilsol And that's what password_verify is for, which is also the subject of the question. You're generating a lot of noise here.

Comment: Hey guys im aware the code isnt the cleanest it isnt something going live I am just tryign to understand how this works. I wouldn't dream of putting this into a real world application;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you used `mysqli_*` functions. But if you don't use the prepared statements, it is not going to help you anyway. Here is a better use of `mysqli_*` functions with prepared statements along with the solution of your problem -

First get the hashed password from DB by username.

```
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password']; 

//NO NEED of stripslashes if using prepared statements.

$sql="SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);

/* bind parameters for markers */
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();

/* store result (So that you can check num_rows immediately.) */
$stmt->store_result();
```

If no rows found you can already throw the "Invalid User" error! Otherwise, just use `password_verify()` for verifying the password this way -

```
if($stmt->num_rows()) {
    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($hashed_password);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
        //Login
    } else {
        //Password mismatch
    }
 } else {
    //User not found.
 }
/* free result */
$stmt->free_result();

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();
```

> If you use prepared statements properly, you will not need to use `stripslashes()` anymore. Just remove these 2 lines:

```
$username = stripslashes($username); //REMOVE THIS LINE
$password = stripslashes($password); //REMOVE THIS LINE
```

Comment: Call me stupid but that second parameter `$hashed_password` where does it get that from?

Comment: Already declared in the previous line and the comment beside it already mentioned "Get from the returned row", I this OP knows, how to get data into variable from a result row.

Comment: I must be getting this all confused in my head - it looks like it should be simple but I am over complicating it I think. I have altered by code to the above and now the page fails

Comment: You have something wrong with `stripslashes` let me update my answer.

Comment: I am now getting the error ` Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()` which I am presuming is a driver issue? I am using php 5.6.13

Comment: Try this way and let me know if still errors, `mysqli_stmt_get_result ( $stmt )` .

Comment: Which line am I replacing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100594/discussion-between-tareq-mahmood-and-dan).

Answer (score 14):

Essentially `password_hash` creates a hash with something called a **salt**. This salt is unique to this hash and is the first few characters of the hash and running password_hash again will give you a different salt as it's randomly generated.

The salt is added to the password in the hashing process to avoid attacks such as just looking at a database of hashes for your result. Take the following as an example:

```
$2a$10$4m/TjukW7De5OszVFYL9quIXNz5pSDc2P.jX5A138G493Vqr0vUiO
```

`$2a` is the identifier saying that the hash is bcrypt

`$10$` is telling us to hash with 10 rounds of bcrypt

`4m/TjukW7De5OszVFYL9qu` is the salt

`IXNz5pSDc2P.jX5A138G493Vqr0vUiO` this is the hashed value.

So, effectively if you just use `password_hash` to generate the hash, it's going to generate a different random salt and therefore the hash is going to be different. The `password_verify` function grabs your already created hash, takes the salt out of it and hashes your value using the salt that you have.

`password_verify($value, $hash)` is used as `$value` will be the password the user inputs and `$hash` is needed for the salt and the amount of rounds from our old hash.

Comment: This is the only answer explaining why you should use `password_verify` instead of just generating a new hash from the entered password and query for that. If could be more complete if you explain that password_hash might change to different hashing algorithms, which would also transparently be covered by `password_verify`. And lastly, it wouldn't hurt to suggest to store a new hash of the password after a user logs in. That way, you will automatically update the password with a stronger hash if a new version would come available, again, completely transparently.

Comment: So would i put the salt in the same file as the login script?

Comment: The salt is stored as part of the HASH, you dont need to worry about it, and of course it is used by `password_verify()` to verify the user entered text string password is the same as the password that was hashed with `password_hash()` originally

Answer (score -3):

password_hash and password_verify use bcrypt at the time of writing. bcrypt will not give you back the same string every time you hash your password.

steps to use a hash from the database:

1. Select the user by username or email
2. If not found, display error or redirect back to form.
3. use password_verify